# Watir - file_field call is clicking on the wrong element when driving Chrome

Tags: selenium, webdriver, watir

Working on a web page that contains a form with a choose file input as in the following snippet:

```
<form ... >
<div class="form__wrap">
  <ul class="form__list">
    Import: 
    <label for="fileUploadInput" class="btn mediaChoose inline" id="fileUpload">Choose File</label>
    <input class="mediaFile" id="fileUploadInput" name="file" type="file" />
  </ul>
</div>
...
</form>
```

Using Watir WebDriver, the following returns true:

```
puts file_field(:id => "fileUploadInput").exists?
```

but, the file_field call below results in the following error on Chrome (works on Firefox and IE):

```
file_field(:id => "fileUploadInput").set(pathtofile)

Element is not clickable at point (695, 314). Other element would receive the click:
<label for="fileUploadInput" class="btn mediaChooseinline" id="fileUpload">...</label>
```

Comment: Is "pathtofile" a reference to a variable that stores the file directory path?

Comment: yes, pathtofile is just a reference to a variable that stores a valid path to the file

Comment: Since you edited/removed the quotes (i.e. "pathtofile" to pathtofile), do you still get an error?

Comment: Yes, the error is still there... the pathtofile is just an example

Comment: OK.  Search SO for `Element is not clickable at point`.  There are answers that suggest that this error happens when a page element exists but isn't displayed within the browser's viewable area.

Comment: The element is actually in the browser's viewable area. It seems to be attempting to act on the label based on the error message. I just realized that part was cut off, so edited it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are driving Chrome, since I have seen errors like that before. The error message is saying that you are trying to click file upload element, but label is displayed over it, so clicking the desired coordinates on the screen will click the label instead of file upload element. Chrome gets confused at that point and refuses to click.

To make sure that is the problem, try the same code with another browser, Fireofox for example. Experience has shown that Firefox does not care if another element will receive the click.

Comment: Yes @Željko Filipin, you are correct, it does work in Firefox and IE.  Do you know if there is a work around for driving Chrome?  Thanks for your insight.

Comment: What I usually do in similar situation is to execute some javascript to make the element clickable by chrome. The tricky part is to figure out the javascript snippet. :) If you are not familiar with javascript, that could be a problem. To execute javascript on a page, do something like this: `@browser.execute_script("funky javascript")`

Comment: Great idea...  if I can figure out the proper javascipt, I will post it here.

Comment: Got it! I used the javascript to strip the class out of the label tag and that moved it out of the way. `execute_script("$(\"label.classname\").removeClass(\"classname inline\")")` Thanks so much for your help @Željko Filipin

Answer (score 0):

I tried a scaled down form similar to your posted form and it has worked for me in Chrome and Firefox.  This was tested on a Windows machine.  I did notice that FireFox and Chrome have different syntaxes for the path directory.

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
Import:
<label for="fileUploadInput" class="btn mediaChoose inline" id="fileUpload" >test</label>
<input class="mediaFile" id="fileUploadInput" name="file" type="file" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Test Code

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto "C:\\Users\\mike\\ruby\\chrome1.html"

puts browser.file_field(:id => "fileUploadInput").exists?
#browser.file_field(:id => "fileUploadInput").set("c:\\Windows\\")  #chrome
browser.file_field(:id => "fileUploadInput").set("c:\\Windows\\..")  #firefox
browser.file_field(:id => "fileUploadInput").click
```

Comment: This code works on Firefox and IE. I believe it is Chrome specific as Željko Filipin is suggesting, so I updated the original question to reflect this. Now wondering if there is a workaround for Chrome?